# Rest API - expected http code response for list items

Tags: list, rest, api

**Scenario**:
The following Rest api list products that belong to a specific order (given its id in the path {orderid})

/api/order/{orderid}/products

What is the best/recommended response for

/api/order/123/products where order 123 does not exists and why?

Options

1. 404 Not Found
2. 200 with empty array
3. Other

Comment: Possible duplicate of [REST API code/message for missing parent resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15384260/rest-api-code-message-for-missing-parent-resource)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[404](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.4) indicates a [client error](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5), that "the origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists".

Roughly, you are reporting to the client (and the intermediary components) that *the client made a mistake in asking for that resource*.

That's likely to be a good choice - the fact that the resource is listed as a path segment implies a [hierarchy](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3), and it's likely that if a resource doesn't exist, than neither do its subordinate resources.

In other words, if `/api/order/123` returns a 404, then it is semantically consistent (but not required) that all resources with the prefix `/api/order/123/` *also* return 404.

> why?

Because the actual implementation of your servers is supposed to be hidden behind the uniform interface.

The point of the uniform interface is that the client can't tell that it isn't talking to a generic 1990s web site.  As far as it is concerned, `/api/order/123/products` could be a file named products in a directory named `/api/order/123`.

So what would happen on a file system if we tried to read from that path when the directory didn't exist?  The file system would return an error (ENOENT ?) and then the web server would usually return a 404 response to the client.

Your REST API is an adapter, that makes your system look like a web site.